# filter from chrome tabs all urls that match list of given urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write javascript that filters out all chrome tabs that match list of urls

so if I have 10 tabs open, it should give me tabs which are matching the 'input list of tabs'.

I tried with help of combination of links

```
let urlLists = ['youtube.com', 'cnn.com']
chrome.tabs.query({ "url": urlLists.includes(p => `*://${p}/*`) }, (tabs) => {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
          console.log('tab.id: ',tab.id, 'tab.url:', tab.url);
}
```

However, it's not working. Any other suggestion or easier way to do it?

I don't have permissions issue. The following code outputs all the tabs

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
          console.log('tab.id: ',tab.id, 'tab.url:', tab.url);
        })
    })
```

---EDIT---
based on @wOxxOm reply, the answer that works

```
let blockUrlList = ["youtube.com", "dict.cc"]
chrome.tabs.query({ "url": blockUrlList.map(p => `*://*.${p}/*`)}, (tabs) => {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        console.log('tab.id: ',tab.id, 'tab.url:', tab.url)
    })
})
```

Thank you @wOxxOm

Comment: Replace `includes` with `map`

Comment: @Yogi, not using manifest as user is entering (and removing) the urls in the options screen

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunately that also does not seem to work. In the options tab user entered 'youtube.com' and 'cnn.com' where as when I print tab.url it shows https://www.youtube.com/. Could that be the reason?

Comment: youtube.com is actually `www.youtube.com`, [your browser is lying to you](https://superuser.com/a/1498561), so you also need to add `*.` after `*://`

Comment: @wOxxOm, you trick did the work. I another question about sync. but I will another another question to keep this logical